# Business mail do not receive Php mail()

Tags: php, email

It's my first time asking a question on this site. (yes, I know, my english is bad)

I'm doing an online christmas card that send the link to the card via mail. My issue is when I tried to sent it to my business mail(@businessname.com), it do not receive the mail at all in outlook, but it work fine when I send it to my gmail or my hotmail.

After looking around, it might be a problem with the spam filter of the company mailing system

```
$to = $case4;
$subject = 'Christmas card from ' . $case1;
$url = "http://mysite.com/folder/index.php?action=see&id=" . $id;
$message = 'Hi ' . $case3 . ',<br />Your friend ' . $case1 . ' sent you this card!<br /><a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank">Click here to see it</a>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Anyone know how I can solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: which outlook? desktop software or online service?

Comment: outlook 2010 both desktop and online

Comment: Well certainly we cannot say much about your companies spam filter. But good spam protection systems add an explanation to the messages header about _why_ a messages has been marked as spam. So find your message in the spam tub and find out what problems the spam protectioon system sees.

Comment: The mail doesnt even get in the spam folder

Comment: I have bad experience with Outlook service. Its better to use google apps mail for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mail` command will invoke the local `sendmail` program to send mail. This results in the webhost sending mail. Spamfilters not only look at the mail's content but certainly also at origin and headers. Try using an SMTP solution from a renowned mail sending service (if you have Gmail, you can use their SMTP servers), for example by utilising the [`Mail` package](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected) from PEAR.

In addition, use [`Mail_Mime`](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/redirected) to correctly create MIME encoded messages.

Comment: I used php mailer and it work fine now. Thanks